# Population genetics modelling in python

Tags: python, population, genetics

so I need to make a program that generates generations of random equally fit alleles of a theoretical organism with a single gene.

I start with a list containing one mutated allele 2, and then I choose 3 alleles for the next generation, and append them to the list for the next generation

```
import random

p = [1,1,1,2]

from random import choice
n=len(p)-1

for i an range(n):
    p.append(choice(p))
```

problem is, this does not remove the allele that was not chosen. 
how can I adapt this program so that the non-chosen allele is removed from the list?

thanks

-
edit

the out put of the program would look something like this

[1,1,1,2,1,2,1]

this would represent a population of 7 organisms with the 2 different alleles. This represents the 2nd generation as there are double alleles of the 3 chosen alleles. this simulated 2 offspring of the 3 chosen alleles.
but the alleles that was not chosen (in this case 1) should not be present in this generation.
so what I want to know is how to remove it from the list here

nb. sorry about being a bit verbose

Comment: Aren't there 3 alleles that are not chosen? Sorry - just trying to understand the question.

Comment: sorry, there are 3 alleles chosen.

Comment: and there are 4 alleles, I want to remove the 1 allele that itn't chosen

Comment: For those of us who are genetically incompetent, could you show what the output is supposed to look like? :)

Comment: In your code, what is `p`? is it one generation of the evolving population? Also, does the size of `p` increase over time?

Comment: Have you given a try to my piece of code? I guess this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random 
n = 4 

A = [i for i in xrange(n)]
B = [1,1,1,2]
NextGeneration = [] 
for i in xrange(n-1):
    last = n - i - 1
    actualChoice =  random.randint(0,last)   
    NextGeneration.append(B[A[actualChoice]])  
    auxSwap = actualChoice 
    A[actualChoice] = A[last]
```

Comment: been programming for about a week, so it's a bit advanced for me, but see the general idea and find it useful, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but here's an attempt at a solution:

```
first_gen = [1,1,1,2]
second_gen = first_gen + random.sample(first_gen, len(first_gen)-1)
```

Does that help at all?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample As far as I understand that's what he is looking for